# 'X questions with new activity' now has smaller link target

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

Prior to today (Aug 25), when the 'X questions with new activity' bar would appear on my feed of questions, I am fairly certain that the entire gray bar was clickable to load the new questions. However, it appears that now the only link target is the actual text.

Was there a reason for this change? Can we go back to the old way? It is a minor annoyance, but it is certainly one of the things I click most on SO, and having a large surface to click was nice.

Comment: It is being fixed, see the answer there

Comment: No problem, good you noticed it and reported here

Comment: Should be fixed now